# Реверсия массива

Tags: c++

такой вопрос:

> Программа должна считывать файл и записывать его задом наперед.

Вроде бы, все ок, но появляется неинициализированная память и из-за этого последний элемент не записывается, а первый заполнен мусором
вот сам код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int L = 0;
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    string path = "file.txt";

    ifstream fin;
    fin.open(path);
    if (!fin.is_open())
    {
        cout << "ошибка" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "файл открылся" << endl;
        int i = 0;
        int k = 0;
        int j = 0;
        char arr;
        char ch[1248];

        while (fin.get(arr))
        {
            ch[i] = arr;
            i++;
            cout << arr;
        }
        cout << endl << " Длинна массива " << i <<endl;

        for (j = 0; j <= i / 2; j++) {
            int t = ch[i - j];
            ch[i - j] = ch[j];
            ch[j] = t;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            cout << ch[j];
        }

        /* for (k = 0; k < i; k++) {
            cout << ch[k];
        } */
    }
    fin.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А зачем вам переворачивать массив, если вам достаточно лишь записать его задом наперед?

Comment: оффтоп: j < i / 2.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, вы считываете данные из файла и записываете их в массив не заботясь о выходе за пределы массива. Во-вторых, зачем вы переварачиваете массив? Вам же нужно просто записать его в обратном порядке.

Хочу предложить, как мне кажется, более красивое решение (за исключением того, что оно не подойдет для огромных файлов, так как я, как и вы в вашем коде, считываю данные полностью):

```cpp
// main.cpp

#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    std::cerr << "you must set input and output filenames" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::string input  = argv[1];
  std::string output = argv[2];

  std::ifstream fin{input, std::ios_base::in};
  if (!fin.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "file cant not be opened" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::string str{std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{fin},
                  std::istreambuf_iterator<char>{}};

  std::ofstream fout{output, std::ios_base::out};
  if (!fout.is_open()) {
    std::cerr << "can not open out file" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  std::copy(str.rbegin(), str.rend(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>{fout});

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ch[i - 1 - j] должно быть. Поэтому первый элемент не инициализируется - инициализируется последний плюс один элемент. У вас сдвиг вправо.